# Continuous predictor of a significant difference on another scale at T1 and T2

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, continuous-data

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction for a statistical test.

I’m looking whether a continous variable (e.g. a personality variable) predicts a significant difference between scores on another continous scale taken at two time points (e.g. anxiety, taken at Time 1 and Time 2).

Does anybody have any idea what types of tests might be appropriate? I’m using SPSS primarily.

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward approach would be to calculate the difference scores (i.e., for each participant, Anxiety at T2 - Anxiety at T1) and see whether that difference is associated with the participants' predictor value. If a scatter plot shows the relationship between the predictor variable and those difference scores to be approximately linear, you could report a Pearson correlation coefficient with its associated t- and p-values.

Comment: Thankyou Janhove. I really appreciate your help. Your suggestion is actually what I did first. However, it doesn't test whether the difference between Anxiety@T1 and T2 is statistically significant as a function of personality. Instead, it explores whether self-monitoring predicts the size of the difference irrespective of that difference being statistically significant (I hope that made sense?). I agree with you that the approach is straightforward and very simple to do - but doesn't exactly look at my specific research question/hypothesis, which I will have difficulty changing.

Comment: Aside from Janhove's suggestion, I'm tempted by using some form of multi-level modelling (in SPSS, I think this is known as mixed effects. I'm more familiar with SEM than MLM so it is a bit new to me).

However, I wanted to see if anybody else had other ideas that I am missing or had similar experiences to share about tests that are appropriate to test the research question I outlined.

Comment: "I hope that made sense?" Not really, to be honest. Would you like to end up with an answer like: "For low levels of self-monitoring (values up till 5), the T2-T1 anxiety difference is n.s.; for higher levels it is."? I can't imagine a situation where such an answer would be preferable to something like "T2-T1 differences in anxiety correlate positively with self-monitoring levels (see Fig. 1 for scatter plot)".
(Fitting an interaction term between 'Time' and 'Self-monitoring' in an RM-ANCOVA or a mixed-model should give you the same result as the easier gain score analysis, I think.)